# Switch between different 'child' view controllers using a toolbar and its buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Does anyone have any tips for this scenario.

My app delegate's nib has a viewcontroller set as the rootviewcontroller, so it loads this view controller when the app loads.

This viewcontroller has a toolbar with various buttons.  These buttons are meant to switch between different view controllers.

I have tried using addChildViewController, presentViewController, presentModalViewController nothing allows me to switch between view controllers BUT still keep the toolbar visible.

If I use addSubView then all the orientation stuff goes mental and I have to resize the view controller manually which doesn't seem like something I should be doing.

EDIT:  I want to keep the nav controller's button visible even when pushing controllers on i.e. if I have an EDIT and DELETE button I want those same buttons to remain on the toolbar even when I push different controllers onto the stack

Comment: what example are you working off? Or did you use a template project?

Comment: are you using a navigation, tab bar or split view controller?

Comment: @MaxMacLeod am using a nav controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using a tab bar.

Alternatively, you should be using a navigation controller with a toolbar and push/pop view controllers on this when the toolbar buttons are pressed:

Please note the navigation bar does not have to be visible if you use a navigation controller.

```
    //create first button
    buttonOne = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"EDIT" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(editStuff)];
    [buttons addObject:buttonOne];

    //create second button
    buttonTwo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"DELETE" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(deleteStuff)];
    [buttons addObject:buttonTwo];


    // Add buttons to toolbar and toolbar to nav bar.
    [buttonsToolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
    [buttons release];

    UIBarButtonItem *twoButtons = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonsToolbar];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = twoButtons;
    [twoButtons release];
```

Comment: Thanks @ade I am gonna try using a nav controller with NO animation see how it looks and then mark correct.

Comment: what a mission.  changed everything to use navigation controller but I don't want to see the <back button I want to keep the root nav controller's buttons visible

Comment: self.navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

Comment: [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];

Comment: I want the original buttons to appear in the tool bar see my edit

Comment: just recreate the toolbar when you push/pop a new viewcontroller e.g. in viewWillAppear, code now in an answer above.

Answer (score 0):

`addSubview:` doesn't permit use of a secondary view controller, so that's not ideal.

You can use a toolbar with bar buttons to switch view controllers, but the simplest implementation is to have identical toolbars in each view controller's nib, and make the view controllers subclasses of a superclass that handles all of the toolbar actions.

There is no need to use a tab bar or navigation bar, although either of these would be a simpler approach in someways (but less obvious in the ways that matter).

Comment: In iOS 5 you can definitely use `addSubview` to add a view of another view controller into the mix, but you *must* match it with a call to `addChildViewController` on the parent VC you're adding said sub-view controller to (bit of a mouthful there). That way your secondary view controller will receive all the various rotation and appearance calls the parent will.

Comment: Exactly - you can't steal a view from another view controller with addSubview:.  I think the OP will get the best experience by using a single view controller in his example, given his comment about trying different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use a UITabBarController as your root controller. This acts as a parent container for your child viewcontrollers, provides a tab bar and implements switching between child views. Check out the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or the [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)